# Japid or Scala which one is better?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, japid

Japid is a fast template engine (probably 2x to 20x faster) supported by play framework, But is it better enough or stable enough to be used in production environment ? And if japid is better than why play shipped examples projects in scala?

Comment: I have never heard of Japid, so my soon-to-come advise might not actually apply, but: such a question ("is Foo production-ready?") is often better asked on the project's mailing list than on SO, especially if the project is not widely known.

Comment: x20 faster than groovy template, but not scala

Answer (score 2):

Japid is not faster because it is written in Java.  It's faster because the people who wrote it decided to spend the effort to make it faster.  Scala can be just as fast.

It's also <strike>newer, and</strike> a plugin, which explains why it isn't used for the core examples for Play.

Comment: Especially since it's a plugin. Not because of maturity. It's has been around since the first versions of Play 1.x.